# Files Upload to Salesforce, but not Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, lightning, files

Off of [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166052/can-i-upload-files-as-attachments-in-lightning-experience), I attempted to write code to upload a file to the Files tab in lightning exeperience.  Here is the code I used from [the salesforce guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm):

```
01<!-- Upload a file and put it in your personal documents folder-->
02 
03<!-- Page: -->
04 <apex:page standardController="Document" extensions="documentExt">
05    <apex:messages />
06    <apex:form id="theForm">
07      <apex:pageBlock>
08          <apex:pageBlockSection>
09        <apex:inputFile value="{!document.body}" filename="{!document.name}"/>
10            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
11          </apex:pageBlockSection>
12       </apex:pageBlock>
13    </apex:form>
14</apex:page>
15                 
16  /*** Controller ***/
17 public class documentExt {
18    public documentExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
19        Document d = (Document) controller.getRecord();
20    d.folderid = UserInfo.getUserId(); //this puts it in My Personal Documents
21    }                
22 }
```

It works perfectly....but only on the original salesforce page.

[image]

The Files tab on the lightning page looks like this:

[image]

There are numerous things I have tried to install or read about [on the guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/05/build-lightning-file-uploader-component.html), [on github](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files), and [on the salesforce forum](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pL5mQAE) but none of them seem to properly place the files in the Files tab of lightning.

What functionality could I add to apex to simply upload the files, content and all, to the Files tab in Lightning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting record into document object and Document object is different than files object in Lightning Experience .

Files represent Content Version Object.Try creating a content version record

```
public class contentController {

public contentController() {
    file = new ContentVersion();
}

  public ContentVersion file { get; set; }

  public PageReference go() {
    insert file;
    return new PageReference('/' + file.id);
   }
}
```

The Visualforce page is as below

```
<apex:page controller="contentController">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:inputFile value="{!file.versionData}" fileName="{!file.pathOnClient}" />
    <apex:commandbutton action="{!go}" value="go"/>
   </apex:form>
 </apex:page>
```

Here is a neat [blog](http://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2010/04/1845.html) on the same .

Comment: For others that will see this answer, the code does not work as written, but the  code in the blog link does.

Comment: @BenjaminSarkis I just changed the code to mirror the blog .Thanks