# How to attach a document in lightning, not a ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, lightning-experience

We are finally rolling into lightning, but I am having an issue as sometimes we have user that upload a certain doc type into the system, when this type of files are uploaded it triggers some special actions.

I notice that lightning doesnt create an attachment when manually loading a file, it creates a record in an object called: contentdocumentlink, for hence my trigger is never excecuted.

Why lightning decide to do this?
How can i create a normal attachment (in lightning)?
or how can i make this to trigger my trigger?

Comment: you might want to look into this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/166052/can-i-upload-files-as-attachments-in-lightning-experience

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a user upload a file manually in lightning without enabling the salesforce files by going setup--> general setting--> Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments ,  still it is saved as salesforce files.

You need to understand that not only ContentDocumentLink is getting created, but two other also are there(ContentVersion and contentDocument).

> Example:- if a user upload a file manually on a account record, These
>   things will happen simultaneously:-
>
> - 2 ContentDocumentLink(One with Account record, an another with the user who has uploaded it)
> - 1 ContentVersion
> - 1 ContentDocument

If your trigger is written on attachment it will not fire. Now coming to Your question "**why Lightning Decided to do this**" :-

> Why convert attachments to Salesforce files?
>       Files are more versatile and provide better functionality than attachments. Attachments can only be
>       attached to a single record, while files:
>
> - Can be shared with multiple records and users
> - Appear in Files home and can be added to Libraries
> - Track multiple versions
> - Provide file previews of documents, images, PDFs, and more
> - Size: up to 2GB, other options goes from 20K to 2GB in dependence of API used
>
> Why convert classic notes to enhanced notes? Enhanced notes are more
>   versatile and provide better functionality than classic notes. Classic
>   notes can only be attached to the records of one object. Enhanced
>   notes, however, can be added to multiple objects, like accounts,
>   opportunity, contact, and lead. Enhanced notes are optimized for
>   Lightning Experience. They can also be used in Salesforce1.

**How can i create a normal attachment (in lightning)?**

> Salesforce files are optimized for Lightning Experience.
>       Attachments can’t be uploaded in Lightning Experience. Attachments may be visible (and read-only) in
>       Lightning Experience, but only if the org admin has enabled this on each page layout.

**or how can i make this to trigger my trigger?**
  You need to refractor your code to make it fire. For Insert or update, write your trigger on ContentDocumentLink and for delete , write your trigger on ContentDocument.

Note:- if you write insert, update and delete trigger on ContentDocumentLink, many a times delete trigger will not fire many a times. May be some org will achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes lightning uses ContentDocumentLink. [This is because notes/attachments features are losing support.](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_files_add_related_list_to_page_layouts.htm) You should not be using these features moving forward.

**You can however, create a trigger on the ContentDocumentLink object that does the exact same thing as your attachment trigger.** This way your trigger fires as needed and your code will continue to work for a very very long time.

This is a part of lightning migration and you should embrace it, not avoid it.

### Tips n Tricks

When I first started working with ContentDocumentLink and SF files I had a hard time understanding some of the differences so here's some notes:

- ContentDocumentLink is a junction object that associates a ContentDocument to any record via the `ContentDocumentId` and `LinkedEntityId` fields
- ContentDocumentVersion is the record that actually contains the document. When ever a modification is made to a ContentDocument, it is done via inserting a new version. The `IsLatest` field can be used to make sure you are working with the most recent version. The `versiondata` field contains the actual document blob. We use this field to send documents via rest to DocuSign for instance
- ContentDocument contains high level information about the document
- QuoteDocument is a variation of ContentDocumentLink in that it links quotes directly to ContentVersoins. This is the object that is used when you use the `Create PDF` button from the quote page layout. This object varies from ContentDocumentLink in that it can only be associated to quotes (`QuoteId` field) and relates to ContentDocumentVersions as opposed to ContentDocuments via the `ContentdocumentVersionId` field
- I forget exactly which object it is (sorry) but one of the objects specifically requires a WHERE on an ID field (I think it's CDL) It's a good idea to always get your documents in relation to a parent object for efficiency and to avoid errors

### Example

If you want to get the most recent quote pdf for all quotes in a trigger

```
List<ContentVersion> cvs = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM ContentVersion
    WHERE IsLatest = true
        AND Id IN (
            SELECT ContentDocumentVersionId
            FROM QuoteDocument
            WHERE QuoteId IN :Trigger.New
        )
];
```

### Example CDL Trigger

```
trigger testTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after insert, after update) {
    Map<Id, Id> parentToDocument = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Map<Id, ContentVersion> docToMostRecentVersion = new Map<id, ContentVersion>();
    List<Docusign.Envelope> envelopes = new List<DocuSign.Envelope>();
    List<DocusignStatus__c> statuses = new List<DocuSignStatus__c>();

    for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : trigger.new) {
        parentToDocument.put(cdl.LinkedEntityId, cdl.ContentDocumentId);
    }

    for (ContentVersion cv : [
        SELECT Id, VersionData, ContentDocumentId
        FROM ContentVersion
        WHERE IsLatest = true
            AND ContentDocumentId IN :parentToDocument.values()
    ]) {
        docToMostRecentVersion.put(cv.ContentDocumentId, cv);
    }

    for (Opportunity opp : [
        SELECT Id, (
            SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.Email
            FROM OpportunityContactRoles
        )
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id IN :parentToDocument.keySet()
    ]) {
        envelopes.add(new DocuSign.Envelope(
            opp.OpportunityContactRoles,
            docToMostRecentVersion.get(parentToDocument.get(opp.Id))
        ));
    }

    if (!envelopes.isEmpty()) {
        DocuSign.send(envelopes);
    }

    for (DocuSign.Envelope env : envelopes) {
        statuses.add(new DocuSignStatus__c(
            Opportunity__c = opp.Id,
            Evelope__c = env.Id
        ));
    }

    if (!statuses.isEmpty()) {
        insert statuses;
    }
}
```

### If you choose to ignore everything I just said

You can still create attachments in lightning you'll just have to customize the behavior by developing new components to handle the file upload. I'm not going to provide any examples as I don't support this avenue but it's possible. Just google HTML file uploads and pass the file to an `@aureEnabled` method.

You can also create a rest service that accepts a post and use JS to shoot the file out to the service. There's probably more ways to achieve this as well but you'll have to research these solutions on your own.