# Opportunity Trigger?

Tags: trigger

I need a trigger that will force the user to add an attachment before moving onto the next stage and also where they can't delete the attachment, only admin could.

Comment: Post the part you have tried so far, that helps to know where you are stuck

Answer (score 2):

First thing to keep in mind is that **attachments are losing support so you shouldn't use them anymore**. Instead you should use `ContentDocuments`. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228920/how-to-attach-a-document-in-lightning-not-a-contentdocumentlink/228921#228921) goes over why you shouldn't use attachments as well as provides information about content documents and the structure of a content document.

To stop users from deleting documents:

```
trigger ContentDocumentTrigger on ContentDocument (before delete) {
    Id adminProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id;

    if (UserInfo.getProfileId() != adminProfileId) {
        for (ContentDocument cd : trigger.new) {
            cd.addError('Only admins can delete content documents');
        }
    }
}
```

**You might want to replicate the trigger on the ContentVersion object as well.**

If you want to stop people from moving stages on an opp until a document is attached you can do:

```
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (before update) {
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsWithCDLs = [
        SELECT Id, (
                SELECT Id
                FROM ContentDocumentLinks
            )
       FROM Opportunity
       WHERE Id IN :trigger.new
    ];

    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new) {
        if (
            opp.stageName == 'New Stage' && 
            trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).stageName == 'Old Stage' &&
            oppsWithCDLs.get(opp.Id).contentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()
        ) {
            opp.addError('Attach file before moving to the next stage');
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** We use numbers in our stage names such as 1, 2, 3, etc. This allows us to do something like:

```
Integer stage = integer.valueOf(opp.stageName.left(1));
Integer stageRequiresAttachment = 3;

if (stage >= stageRequiresAttachment) {
    // Throw error
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it man but I'm asking in regards to Notes and Attachments. Also any idea why people are downvoting me? I'm new to this, what did I do wrong to get down voted multiple times?

Comment: You could optimize that query in the second block of code with an AggregateResult map/set: `Id[] oppIds = new List<Id>(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    Set<Id> oppsWithContent = new map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT LinkedEntityId Id 
         FROM ContentDocumentLink 
         WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :oppIds
         GROUP BY LinkedEntityId]
    ).keyset();` This slightly reduces memory usage if there happens to be a lot of files attached.

Comment: The biggest reason you got down-voted was that you show no evidence that you attempted a solution on your own. We generally don't like "do it for me" type posts. There is a ton of documentation telling you not to use notes and attachments anymore. I won't help you with that but if someone else pops up and is willing you might get what you're looking for.